# plt.bar(x,y) throws "AttributeError"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar graph in pyspark using matplotlib. However, I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update' on executing plt(x,y). Here x is a list of strings and y is a list of ints.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
>>> x
['SOUTH AFRICA', 'BAHAMAS', 'ARMENIA', 'JAPAN', 'BANGLADESH', 'UGANDA', 'GY1 4HY', 'JERSEY', 'TANZANIA', 'JORDAN', 'MALTA', 'ALBANIA', 'BELARUS', 'LANCS', 'SCOTLAND', 'MAURITIUS', 'KUWAIT', 'TAJIKSTAN', 'LITHUANIA', 'GY1 2HL', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'AZERBAIJAN', 'EAST SUSSEX', 'PHILIPPINES', 'SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS', 'CZECH REPUBLIC', None, 'OMAN', 'HONG KONG  CHINA', 'CV31 3RG', 'FIJI', 'COSTA RICA', 'SOUTH KOREA', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND UNITED KINGDOM', 'POLAND', 'SLOVAKIA', 'GRENADA', 'SRI LANKA', 'COLOMBIA', 'VANUATU', 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', 'ALGERIA', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', 'GIBRALTAR', 'SOUTH-WEST AFRICA', 'NORTHERN IRELAND UNITED KINGDOM', 'GUERNSEY', 'U', 'ENGLAND', 'DOMINICA', 'LIBERIA', 'MOROCCO', 'DUMMY', 'REUNION', 'MEXICO', 'CAMEROON', 'PAKISTAN', 'ANGUILLA', '1200', 'BURUNDI', 'FRANCE', 'ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF IRAN', 'CAYMAN ISLANDS', 'GAMBIA', 'BRUNEI DARUSSALAM', 'SAINT LUCIA', 'SINGAPORE', 'MOZAMBIQUE', 'MADAGASCAR', 'CURACAO', 'NIGERIA', 'CHANNEL ISLANDSSW1W 0AU', 'BRITISH VIGIN ISLANDS', 'CHINA', 'AUSTRIA', 'MALAYSIA', 'C', 'ZAMBIA', 'LATVIA', 'NEPAL', 'BOTSWANA', 'SW7', 'KYRGYZSTAN', 'MALI', 'BELIZE', 'ZIMBABWE', 'SAUDI ARABIA', 'CROATIA', 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', 'RWANDA', 'FAROE ISLAND', 'SWITZERLAND', 'BULGARIA', 'KAZAKHSTAN', 'ARGENTINA', 'IVORY COAST', 'SUDAN', 'BRITISH WEST INDIES', 'HONG KONG', 'UKRAINE', 'CZECHOSLOVAKIA', 'SERBIA', 'N', 'BWI', 'NORWAY', 'FINLAND', 'MONGOLIA', 'MALAWI', 'NETHERLANDS', 'WEST INDIES', 'GUYANA', 'SLOVENIA', 'LIVERPOOL', 'SIERRA LEONE', 'UZBEKISTAN', 'IRAN', 'CHANNEL ISLANDS', 'SWEDEN', 'ECUADOR', 'BELGIUM', 'RUSSIA', 'NORTHERN IRELAND', 'TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO', 'NEW ZEALAND', 'CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE', 'CHANNEL ISLES', 'SPAIN', 'MOLDOVA', 'GREECE', 'LEBANON', 'GUINEA', 'INDIA', 'BERMUDA', 'TAIWAN', 'KENYA', 'ICELAND', 'TURKEY', 'COOK ISLANDS', 'FAROE ISLANDS', 'LUXEMBOURG', 'AFGHANISTAN', 'BRITISH CHANNEL ISLANDS', 'YUGOSLAVIA', 'USSR', 'LIECHTENSTEIN', 'TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS', 'URUGUAY', 'SOUTH AFRICAN', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH', 'NETHERLANDS ANTILLES', 'ENGLAND & WALES', 'ITALY', 'AUSTRALIA', 'MONACO', 'PANAMA', 'CHILE', 'IRAQ', 'DENMARK', 'THAILAND', 'HUNGARY', 'CHAD', 'QATAR', 'SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES', 'JAMAICA', 'CONGO', 'VIETNAM', 'CYPRUS', 'SEYCHELLES', 'BRITISH ISLES', 'ETHIOPIA', 'ISRAEL', 'PORTUGAL', 'KOREA', 'INDONESIA', 'YEMEN', 'IRELAND', 'UNITED STATES', 'KY1-9005', 'ROMANIA', 'GERMANY', 'GHANA', 'SCOTLAND  UK', 'ISLE OF MAN', 'BRAZIL', 'LIBYA', 'KOSOVO', 'BARBADOS', 'WALES', 'VENEZUELA', 'EGYPT', 'BAHRAIN', 'PERU', 'PO33 2TG', 'GEORGIA']  

>>> y  
[35, 59, 2, 215, 17, 7, 1, 202, 5, 2, 21, 1, 3, 1, 91225, 21, 9, 2, 3, 1, 1178488, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 1834076, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 76, 191, 1, 14, 1, 1, 20, 2, 2, 38, 1, 177, 82, 1, 5, 67, 2, 1141835, 7, 31, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 29, 3, 1, 1, 179, 1, 359, 4, 1, 1, 76, 2, 1, 4, 80, 1, 1, 96, 22, 30, 1, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 12, 12, 3, 14, 2, 1, 361, 5, 8, 3, 2, 2, 1, 116, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 38, 20, 2, 2, 360, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 24, 350, 39, 1, 99, 25, 21205, 6, 69, 1, 1, 105, 1, 12, 8, 1, 307, 90, 13, 5, 7, 38, 3, 1, 73, 2, 1, 3, 24, 7, 5, 7, 1, 246, 8, 5, 83, 221, 4, 48, 1, 4, 57, 4, 6, 1, 6, 2, 9, 1, 5, 42, 14, 2, 1, 19, 10, 7, 4, 1, 461, 2478, 2, 9, 284, 18, 1, 392, 23, 1, 2, 13, 31984, 3, 11, 11, 1, 1, 2]

>>> plt.bar(x,y)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/applied/sparkVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1810, in inner  
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)  
  File "/home/applied/sparkVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2238, in bar  
    x = self.convert_xunits(x)  
  File "/home/applied/sparkVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 186, in convert_xunits  
    return ax.xaxis.convert_units(x)  
  File "/home/applied/sparkVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1530, in convert_units  
    ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)  
  File "/home/applied/sparkVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py", line 53, in convert  
    unit.update(values)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `None` value in your list. Convert it to string as well, e.g. via

```
plt.bar(np.array(x).astype(str),y)
```

You may add `plt.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)` to rotate the labels to have them not overlapping.

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = ['SOUTH AFRICA', 'BAHAMAS', 'ARMENIA', 'JAPAN', 'BANGLADESH', 'UGANDA', 'GY1 4HY', 'JERSEY', 'TANZANIA', 'JORDAN', 'MALTA', 'ALBANIA', 'BELARUS', 'LANCS', 'SCOTLAND', 'MAURITIUS', 'KUWAIT', 'TAJIKSTAN', 'LITHUANIA', 'GY1 2HL', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'AZERBAIJAN', 'EAST SUSSEX', 'PHILIPPINES', 'SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS', 'CZECH REPUBLIC', None, 'OMAN', 'HONG KONG  CHINA', 'CV31 3RG', 'FIJI', 'COSTA RICA', 'SOUTH KOREA', 'CANADA', 'ENGLAND UNITED KINGDOM', 'POLAND', 'SLOVAKIA', 'GRENADA', 'SRI LANKA', 'COLOMBIA', 'VANUATU', 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES', 'ALGERIA', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', 'GIBRALTAR', 'SOUTH-WEST AFRICA', 'NORTHERN IRELAND UNITED KINGDOM', 'GUERNSEY', 'U', 'ENGLAND', 'DOMINICA', 'LIBERIA', 'MOROCCO', 'DUMMY', 'REUNION', 'MEXICO', 'CAMEROON', 'PAKISTAN', 'ANGUILLA', '1200', 'BURUNDI', 'FRANCE', 'ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF IRAN', 'CAYMAN ISLANDS', 'GAMBIA', 'BRUNEI DARUSSALAM', 'SAINT LUCIA', 'SINGAPORE', 'MOZAMBIQUE', 'MADAGASCAR', 'CURACAO', 'NIGERIA', 'CHANNEL ISLANDSSW1W 0AU', 'BRITISH VIGIN ISLANDS', 'CHINA', 'AUSTRIA', 'MALAYSIA', 'C', 'ZAMBIA', 'LATVIA', 'NEPAL', 'BOTSWANA', 'SW7', 'KYRGYZSTAN', 'MALI', 'BELIZE', 'ZIMBABWE', 'SAUDI ARABIA', 'CROATIA', 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', 'RWANDA', 'FAROE ISLAND', 'SWITZERLAND', 'BULGARIA', 'KAZAKHSTAN', 'ARGENTINA', 'IVORY COAST', 'SUDAN', 'BRITISH WEST INDIES', 'HONG KONG', 'UKRAINE', 'CZECHOSLOVAKIA', 'SERBIA', 'N', 'BWI', 'NORWAY', 'FINLAND', 'MONGOLIA', 'MALAWI', 'NETHERLANDS', 'WEST INDIES', 'GUYANA', 'SLOVENIA', 'LIVERPOOL', 'SIERRA LEONE', 'UZBEKISTAN', 'IRAN', 'CHANNEL ISLANDS', 'SWEDEN', 'ECUADOR', 'BELGIUM', 'RUSSIA', 'NORTHERN IRELAND', 'TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO', 'NEW ZEALAND', 'CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE', 'CHANNEL ISLES', 'SPAIN', 'MOLDOVA', 'GREECE', 'LEBANON', 'GUINEA', 'INDIA', 'BERMUDA', 'TAIWAN', 'KENYA', 'ICELAND', 'TURKEY', 'COOK ISLANDS', 'FAROE ISLANDS', 'LUXEMBOURG', 'AFGHANISTAN', 'BRITISH CHANNEL ISLANDS', 'YUGOSLAVIA', 'USSR', 'LIECHTENSTEIN', 'TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS', 'URUGUAY', 'SOUTH AFRICAN', 'VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH', 'NETHERLANDS ANTILLES', 'ENGLAND & WALES', 'ITALY', 'AUSTRALIA', 'MONACO', 'PANAMA', 'CHILE', 'IRAQ', 'DENMARK', 'THAILAND', 'HUNGARY', 'CHAD', 'QATAR', 'SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES', 'JAMAICA', 'CONGO', 'VIETNAM', 'CYPRUS', 'SEYCHELLES', 'BRITISH ISLES', 'ETHIOPIA', 'ISRAEL', 'PORTUGAL', 'KOREA', 'INDONESIA', 'YEMEN', 'IRELAND', 'UNITED STATES', 'KY1-9005', 'ROMANIA', 'GERMANY', 'GHANA', 'SCOTLAND  UK', 'ISLE OF MAN', 'BRAZIL', 'LIBYA', 'KOSOVO', 'BARBADOS', 'WALES', 'VENEZUELA', 'EGYPT', 'BAHRAIN', 'PERU', 'PO33 2TG', 'GEORGIA']  
y  = [35, 59, 2, 215, 17, 7, 1, 202, 5, 2, 21, 1, 3, 1, 91225, 21, 9, 2, 3, 1, 1178488, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 1834076, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 76, 191, 1, 14, 1, 1, 20, 2, 2, 38, 1, 177, 82, 1, 5, 67, 2, 1141835, 7, 31, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 29, 3, 1, 1, 179, 1, 359, 4, 1, 1, 76, 2, 1, 4, 80, 1, 1, 96, 22, 30, 1, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10, 12, 12, 3, 14, 2, 1, 361, 5, 8, 3, 2, 2, 1, 116, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 38, 20, 2, 2, 360, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 24, 350, 39, 1, 99, 25, 21205, 6, 69, 1, 1, 105, 1, 12, 8, 1, 307, 90, 13, 5, 7, 38, 3, 1, 73, 2, 1, 3, 24, 7, 5, 7, 1, 246, 8, 5, 83, 221, 4, 48, 1, 4, 57, 4, 6, 1, 6, 2, 9, 1, 5, 42, 14, 2, 1, 19, 10, 7, 4, 1, 461, 2478, 2, 9, 284, 18, 1, 392, 23, 1, 2, 13, 31984, 3, 11, 11, 1, 1, 2]

plt.bar(np.array(x).astype(str),y) 
plt.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]